# Not true values plus unsupported operand type error

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code written in python:

```
def FindDeviation(block, v, win):
    h, w = block.shape
    dist = 0
    Dist = 0
    for i in range(0,h-1):
        for j in range(0,w-1):
            print v 
            print block[i,j]
            dist = (v-block[i,j])
            print dist
            dist2 = int(dist)^2
            print dist2
            Dist = Dist + dist2
            print Dist
    DeviationOfBlock = math.sqrt((1/win^2)*Dist)
    return DeviationOfBlock
```

and the result is for example for one block:

```
v = 82.0 
block[i,j] = 1
dist = 81.0
dist2 = 83
Dist = 83
```

However, considering v, block[i,j], dist having true values, dist2 is not powered by 2!!!!! why? what is the reason? 
And finally after some steps I have an error:

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'numpy.float64' and
>   'int'"

Can you please help me?

thanks and regards.

Comment: If you want to iterate over the whole block use `range(h)` and `range(w)`.  Test those expressions if you don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

In python , power operator is `**` , `^` means bitwise `xor` .

```
In [12]: np.array([1,2,3])**2
Out[12]: array([1, 4, 9])
```